# How does mtry affect the speed of randomForest when tuning with cross validation in R?

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I tried to tune my randomForest model with codes below:

```
trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=10)

tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry=1:5)
```

And then I used

```
train(model,data=data,method="rf",ntree=500,trControl=trControl,tuneGrid=tuneGrid)
```

to find for the best mtry

It took about 3 hours to finish

However, when I changed `expand.grid(mtry=1:5)` to `expand.grid(mtry=1:8)`, the codes did not finish in more than 9 hours. I want to ask how does the parameter `mtry` affect the speed of tuning `randomForest`. Or in other words, what exactly does the parameter `mtry` do in the tuning process?

Comment: @12b345b6b78 No, `ntree` is the number of trees built. `mtry` is the number of features tried out at each split to find the most significant. Fewer options to test will make the model run faster, but usually you care more about a metric like accuracy or RMSE more than run time, so `mtry` is optimized accordingly.

Comment: You might want to use method = "ranger". This will use the randomForest from the ranger package and will speed up your code significantly.

Comment: @phiver, Hi, thanks for your advice. I tried to use method = "ranger' but it returns error that says "something is wrong, all the rmse are missing". But the same error did not occur when using method  = "rf"